# CSS direction rtl causes horizontal scroll issue

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I have a bilingual site with two versions Arabic and English. In Arabic version on `<body>` I have applied `style="direction:rtl"` . This is causing an issue to a horizontal scrollbar. When I resize the screen to minimum resolution or zoom-out the screen the scrollbar not appearing seems like `overflow-x: hidden` property is set to it. I tried to `overflow: scroll` but it's not working. Anyone can please help.

Comment: could you show the which will make us clear what is the actual problem. Possible make a fiddle.

Comment: You should apply `style="direction:rtl` in your *Arabic* version, not in your English version

Comment: Sorry Danield typo mistake I have edited my question. its on Arabic not english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Firefox, if you try it in Chrome it works.

You've just met <kbd>[**Bug 992384**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=992384)</kbd>, probably (another) regression of [Bug 192767](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192767).

They're working on it, stay tuned ;)